# Net Core - Value Retention

Tags: asp.net-core, parameters, routes

In net core, when the web project is first opened, I send a value via the route. I keep it as static inside a class. Only this value sent should be kept and not called again later. In other words, the value should not be sent over the route and should be stored in the class just like a cookie. I will send this parameter in the link.

For example: onlineorder.com/restaurantnumber=1244658. I want to keep the restaurant number here in the static variable in the class. Only if I specify it as route, this variable must be sent every time. This is where the real problem starts for me. To summarize briefly,
I will send the restaurantnumber data on the first login to the site. This value will also be kept in a class. This value will not be forgotten in different page transitions. The user will not need this value when they go to onlineorder.com again.

Comment: You can't store values like that, they will be lost for a variety of reasons. For example, the API may be restarted, or you may be running in a web farm with multiple instances of the API.

Comment: So is there any method you recommend? A solution that will get me to my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Statics are statics - one value for everyone. Imagine you have three people, who visit onlineorder.com/restaurantnumber=37273, onlineorder.com/restaurantnumber=82923 and onlineorder.com/restaurantnumber=67587 . They will each have the expectation of seeing *their* restaurant. There's no way to do this if you store the number in a static place because they will overwrite each other.

What you're looking for is to bake the number or a text string (a [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug)) that represents the restaurant into the URL. For example: onlineorder.com/restaurant/bobs-burgers/ , onlineorder.com/restaurant/sallys-salads/ and so on. Then related pages that have to do with the restaurant can have sub-routes - onlineorder.com/restaurant/bobs-burgers/allergy-information/, onlineorder.com/restaurant/bobs-burgers/contact/ and so on. And pages which do not change depending on the restaurant, like onlineorder.com/pay-order/, does not have to involve the restaurant at all. (It does have items from their restaurant in the shopping cart, but those items are stored as entries in the Session state or as cookies. It is not necessary to have one pay-order page per restaurant.)

Comment: As far as I understand, the restaurantnumber value must be included in the route you mean.